# sort results from database by country, state, name alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm trying to pull from a database 'retailers' and display them by country with the US being first. Then in that, sorting alphabetically by state, then by name inside of each state.

It should potentially print like this...

United States

```
 Alabama
     Acme Retail Store
     Another Alphabetized Store

 Florida
     Computer Store

 Wyoming
     Computer Store Also
```

Algeria

```
  Algerian Retail Store
```

Great Britain

```
  English Retail Store
```

etc... etc... etc...

I've got it pulling from the database correctly, just need help sorting it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by 
    case when country = 'usa' then 0 else 1 end asc
    , country asc
    , state asc
    , name asc
```

should do it.